# Compilation error for template class

Tags: c++, templates

I'm beginer in templates and cann't resolve one compiler issue. The problem is in the following:

I have two classes.

```
class TMessage
{
public:
    int Priority;
    TMessageType Type;
    bool operator> (const TMessage& m)
    {
        return m.Priority > Priority;
    }
    bool operator< (const TMessage& m)
    {
        return m.Priority < Priority;
    }
};

template<typename T> class TMessageQueue
{
public:
    T* Buffer;
    int QueueStartOffset;

    void SortMessages(int putPointer)
    {
        std::sort(Buffer+QueueStartOffset,Buffer+ putPointer);
    }
};
```

> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/algorithm:62:0,
>                    from TMessageQueue.h:2,
>                    from TWriterThread.h:2,
>                    from TWriterThread.cpp:1:
>   /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘_RandomAccessIterator std::__unguarded_partition(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, const _Tp&) [with _RandomAccessIterator = TMessage*; _Tp = TMessage]’:
>   /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:2283:70:   required from ‘_RandomAccessIterator std::__unguarded_partition_pivot(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator) [with _RandomAccessIterator = TMessage*]’
>   /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:2315:54:   required from ‘void std::__introsort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Size) [with _RandomAccessIterator = TMessage*; _Size = long int]’
>   /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:5461:36:   required from ‘void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter) [with _RAIter = TMessage*]’
>   TMessageQueue.h:158:60:   required from ‘void TMessageQueue::SortMessages(int) [with T = TMessage]’
>   TMessageQueue.h:143:26:   required from ‘TRetCode TMessageQueue::Put(T&) [with T = TMessage]’
>   TWriterThread.cpp:59:34:   required from here
>   /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:2245:19: error: passing ‘const TMessage’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘bool TMessage::operator<(const TMessage&)’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
>       while (__pivot < *__last)
>                      ^
>   make: *** [all] Error 1

What is the problem? Used compiler g++.

Comment: What is this `TMessageType Type;`?

Comment: What is the "problem"?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and show us the error you get.

Answer (score 3):

The `operator<` and `operator>` methods need to be `const`

```
bool operator> (const TMessage& m) const { ... }
bool operator< (const TMessage& m) const { ... }
```

Comment: That's not what mr. compiler thinks. You need to help him.

Comment: Because the `std::sort` method expects you to provide a comparator which works on const references. You should look at how std::sort is implemented!

Answer (score 0):

In addition the first answer by `simpel01`,

this bad code:

```
   bool operator> (const TMessage& m)
    {
        return m.Priority > Priority;
    }
    bool operator< (const TMessage& m)
    {
        return m.Priority < Priority;
    }
```

In `operator >` must return `this->Priority > m.Priority` not `m.Priority > this->Priority` because `operator >` activated by object `this` and actually you want to say if `I'm` (object this) big than from `m`.

what you do is reverse!

and fix `operator <` to `this->Priority < m.Priority`